# substitute hash key with a different name

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace a Perl hash key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490356/how-to-replace-a-perl-hash-key)
>   [Changing keys in a “for ( keys %hash ) {}”-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431637/changing-keys-in-a-for-keys-hash-loop)

I have a hash like the following

```
test0 => '1'
test1 => '2'
```

I would like to transform it into

```
something0 => '1'
something1 => '2'
```

Basically, I want to take each key from the hash, substitute 'test' with 'something', and put it back into the original hash.

Comment: There are special considerations to changing multiple keys. This not even close to being an exact duplicate of the linked question. (Don't people know what `exact` means???)

Comment: I would say that the problem is not how to transform it, but why do you need to do it in the first place.

Comment: @ikegami : That's not the only instance. Take http://stackoverflow.com/q/2431637/133939 for example.

Answer (score 4):

This works with any 1:1 mapping, even if some keys are the same. This switches a to b (and vice versa):

```
my @new_keys = keys %hash;
y/ab/ba/ foreach @new_keys;
@hash{@new_keys} = delete @hash{keys %hash};
```

The trick is the last line, which uses hash slices to replace all the keys simultaneously, so conflicts don't matter.

### Edit: Benchmarks (now working, thanks @EricStrom)

Here are benchmarks for the methods @ikegami posted (with typos fixed) and also my method above:

```
                Rate  ikegami_map ikegami_5.14  ikegami_for     derobert
ikegami_map  38186/s           --         -16%         -19%         -34%
ikegami_5.14 45547/s          19%           --          -3%         -22%
ikegami_for  47065/s          23%           3%           --         -19%
derobert     58213/s          52%          28%          24%           --
```

Benchmarking code:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(zip);
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);
use v5.14;
use warnings qw(all);

our %hash = zip @{[ 'a'..'z' ]}, @{[ 1..26 ]};
%hash = map { y/a-z/n-za-m/r => $hash{$_} } keys(%hash);

cmpthese(-2, {
    'derobert' => q{
        my @new_keys = keys %hash;
        y/a-z/n-za-m/ foreach @new_keys;
        @hash{@new_keys} = delete @hash{keys %hash};
    },
    'ikegami_for' => q{
        my %new_hash;
        for my $orig (keys(%hash)) {
            (my $new = $orig) =~ y/a-z/n-za-m/;
            $new_hash{$new} = $hash{$orig};
        }
        %hash = %new_hash;
    },
    'ikegami_map' => q{
        %hash = map {
               (my $new = $_) =~ y/a-z/n-za-m/;
               $new => $hash{$_}
            } keys(%hash);
    },
    'ikegami_5.14' => q{
        %hash = map { y/a-z/n-za-m/r => $hash{$_} } keys(%hash);
    },
});
```

Comment: Ps. Here's a variant that leaves any keys that won't change alone:
`my @new_keys = my @old_keys = grep tr/ab//, keys %hash;
tr/ab/ba/ foreach @new_keys;
@hash{@new_keys} = delete @hash{@old_keys};`

Comment: Your benchmark is not working the way you intended.  None of the benchmark routines ever actually see the `%hash` lexical, instead they all see the `%main::hash` global, which is empty.  This can be solved by changing `q{` to `sub{` in each of the tests.  Also, you should never modify the source data set in a benchmark, otherwise, it might throw off the results of other tests.  Each should create a copy of the hash to work on first.

Comment: @EricStrom: Ugh, you're correct. And it made my code look bad :-(. As far as modifying the data in the benchmark, its doing a rot13 on the keys, and a rot13 is its own inverse—so its just repeatedly flipping between state A and state B. Doesn't seem like that should throw anything off (and a copy is fairly expensive compared to the operation being performed)

Answer (score 2):

Using `for` (assumes that every new key is different than every existing key):

```
for my $orig (keys(%hash)) {
    (my $new = $orig) =~ s/^test/something/;
    $hash{$new} = delete($hash{$orig});
}
```

Using `for` (safe to use with any substitution):

```
my %new_hash;
for my $orig (keys(%hash)) {
    (my $new = $orig) =~ s/^test/something/;
    $new_hash{$new} = $hash{$orig};
}
%hash = %new_hash;
```

Using `map` (safe to use with any substitution):

```
%hash = map {
       (my $new = $_) =~ s/^test/something/;
       $new => $hash{$_}
    } keys(%hash);
```

Using `map` and 5.14+  (safe to use with any substitution):

```
%hash = map { s/^test/something/r => $hash{$_} } keys(%hash);
```

Comment: Your `map` method doesn't work due to a typo I'm going to fix for you. Actually, all of them have the same typo. Actually, I'm trying to benchmark them, and please test your code before posting. Typo-filled code confuses beginners!

Answer (score 1):

```
my @keys = keys %hash ;
foreach my $key ( @keys ) {
  my ( $newkey = $key ) =~ s/^test/something/ ;
  $hash{$newkey} = $hash{$key} ;
  delete $hash{$key} ;
}
```

Probably there are shorter versions possible, but this should work.

Comment: You could save a few characters by doing `$hash{$newkey} = delete $hash{$key};`

Comment: It assumes that every new key is different than every existing key, but that's probably a safe assumption.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I could have added some checks, but I wanted to leave this to the OP ;)

Comment: `$hash{$newkey} = $hash{$key} ;` and `delete $hash{$key} ;` can be merged into one line: `$hash{$newkey} = delete $hash{$key} ;`.

Comment: @gpojd Yes, Friedo mentioned that already.

Comment: I don't have any idea how I missed that. Sorry!